# PHP stops script after executing tesseract

Tags: php, pdf, ocr, tesseract

I`ve been working on a script which should do an OCR for an uploaded PDF.
So far so good. I am running PHP 7.3 on nginx and using the laravel framework in an vagrant homestead container. 
The script for the ocr is located in a laravel queue and runs in the background. All PDF files are created from scanner input
PHP has to execute some programs to do the stuff for me

Using:

- GPL Ghostscript 9.26 (2018-11-20)
- ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org
  Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
  License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
  Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP
  Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib
- tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1
  leptonica-1.75.3
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.2) : libpng 
  1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : 
  libopenjp2 2.3.0

The workflow is

- ghostscript to convert the pdf to tiff
- imageMagic to shave the borders and add a new white border (maybe I will remove this only trying this)
- tesseract to do the ocr

Ghostscript and Imagemagic running fine but tesseract sometimes dies without any error only info is killed at the end and script ends. I think, that the Killed info is from PHP and not from Tesseract.

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.0.0-beta.1 with Leptonica
Page 1
Page 2
Page 3
Page 4
Page 5
Page 6
Page 7
Page 8
Page 9
Page 10
Killed
```

in other cases

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.0.0-beta.1 with Leptonica
Page 1
Page 2
null
```

in both cases the tesseract output file is written complete

- I changed the max_execution_time from 30 to 300 seconds - has no effect on the result
- I tried to add a border around the tiff files no effect
- I shaved around 30px of the image and added than a white border of 30px - Tiff files are no very pretty but no effect on ocr result

In all cases it seams that the ocr process was finished. I was able to verify the output file with the original file. All pages are written.

```php
$fileNameWithoutExtension = basename($event->fileName, ".pdf");
$fileName = $event->fileName;
$savePath = $event->savePath;


// Ghost SCript Action
// gs -sDEVICE=tiff24nc -sCompression=lzw -r300x300  -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile="test.tiff" "test.pdf"
$gsCommand = 'gs -sDEVICE=tiffgray -sCompression=lzw -r400x400 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile="' . $savePath . $fileNameWithoutExtension . '.tiff" "'. $savePath . $fileName .'"';
exec($gsCommand);

// Add a border around the image
// convert foo.pdf -bordercolor black -border 10 foo_with_a_10px_border.pdf
$magicCommand = 'convert "' . $savePath . $fileNameWithoutExtension . '.tiff" -shave 30x30 -bordercolor White -border 30  "' . $savePath . $fileNameWithoutExtension . '.tiff"';
exec($magicCommand);

// Teseract Action
$tesseractCommand = 'tesseract "' . $savePath . $fileNameWithoutExtension . '.tiff" "' . $savePath . $fileNameWithoutExtension . '" -l deu';

exec($tesseractCommand);
```

I am struggling at the moment and have no Idea why the process is killed after executing tesseract. Hopefully I can get some help here :)

Timo

Comment: What do the logs say? Confused about "process is killed". Does the script not finish after the `exec` call? What does it return? Finally, not sure where arguments come from. Perhaps should be using [`escapeshellarg`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)?

Comment: Sorry? Found what? Update the question.

Comment: After the last exec is a dump("Finished"); line. This one appears only when there is no Killed msg. Logs show nothing whats help - sorry checked some files while was in editing mode

Comment: What is the "Killed msg"? Not sure what you are referring to. Are your error reporting levels sane... `E_ALL`? Probably can't help if you've nothing to go on. Again, what does the exec call return? Is it simply some permission issue with calling that command from the script?

Comment: There is no error msg. Everything I have is in my post. I think it is a problem with tesseract that is not finishing correctly. When everything is fine it returns Null as you can see in my second case. And the error will not happen every time it will happen if the file has more than 2 pages. I will try to change the code to Crete 1 page Tiff files tomorrow to see if this can solve the problem.

Comment: Perhaps add some exception handling. Evaluate the return value from a successful tesseract call. Or, if there is only strerr, at least do something like `$retval = exec(...` and replace that `dump('finished')` with `dump('finished:' .  $retval);`. Coding and expecting the worse, anticipating it, reporting it when found, not advancing under assumptions, is a good general practice to adopt. eg. "test driven development". Same way you should always be as explicit as possible, `===`... End rant ;)